# Agenda Telefonica C++ Pt2

Tags: c++, linux

Hace unos dias hice una consulta sobre un problema con una agenda que estoy escribiendo en C++. Parecia que habia solucionado el problema. Pero no, jaja. Hay algo que no entiendo.
Dejo el codigo aca abajo.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
struct agenda_telefonica{
    char nombre[30]={"Vacio"};
    char apellido[30];
    int prefijo;
    int telefono;
}contacto[10];

int main(){
    int seleccion,modificador;
    int i;
    char bandera='F';//determina si hay contactos o no
    char retorno='s',nuevocont='s';//para retornar a opciones e ingresar un nuevo contacto

    cout<<"***Agenda Telefonica***\n"<<endl;

    while(retorno=='s'){
        //Menu de opciones de la agenda
        cout<<"\aIngrese una opcion:\n";
        cout<<"1)Imprimir contactos\n";
        cout<<"2)Ingresar un contacto.\n";
        cout<<"3)Modificar un contacto.\n";
        cout<<"4)Eliminar un contacto.\n";
        cin>>seleccion;
        switch(seleccion){//para seleccionar el menu
        case 1://mostrar contactos
            if(bandera=='V'){//se imprimen contactos agendados
                for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                    if(contacto[i].prefijo!=0){//muestra los contactos si prefijo es distinto a 0
                        cout<<"Contacto "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
                        cout<<contacto[i].nombre<<" "<<contacto[i].apellido<<"\n";
                        cout<<contacto[i].prefijo<<"-"<<contacto[i].telefono<<endl;
                    }
                } 
            }else{//Si no hay contactos agendados
            cout<<"***No hay contactos agendados***"<<endl;
            }
        break;
        case 2://ingresar contactos  
            while(nuevocont=='s'){
                cout<<"Ingrese la posicion donde quiere agregar el contacto: ";
                cin>>modificador;
                cin.ignore(256,'\n');//vaciar el buffer en linux 
                cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: ";
                cin.getline(contacto[modificador-1].nombre,30,'\n');
                cout<<"ingrese su apellido: ";
                cin.getline(contacto[modificador-1].apellido,30,'\n');
                cout<<"Ingrese el prefijo: ";
                cin>>contacto[modificador-1].prefijo;
                cout<<"Ingrese su telefono: ";
                cin>>contacto[modificador-1].telefono;

                cout<<"\nDesea ingresar un nuevo contacto? (s/n): ";
                cin>>nuevocont;//para determinar si queremos ingresar otro contacto  
            }
            bandera='V';//Bandera cambia luego de agendar contactos   
        break;
        }
        cout<<"\nDesea seleccionar otra opcion? (s/n): "<<endl;
        cin>>retorno; 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

El problema esta en la opcion 2 del switch. La primera vez que ingreso en la opcion me permite agregar un contacto sin problemas. Luego imprimo los contactos para controlar que esten agregados como corresponde, y vuelvo a ingresar a la opcion 2 para agregar otro contacto, y ahi esta el problema. Ingreso a la opcion 2 y me salta la opcion, y me manda directamente al final del while para decidir si quiero hacer algo mas.

He probado con un for y un while, y en ambos me pasa lo mismo. Alguna idea? Gracias!!

Comment: Son más de cien líneas de código, ¿Seguro que se necesita todo para reproducir el error?

Comment: Perdon, ahi acorte el codigo a las 2 primeras opciones.

Comment: Por favor añade títulos más relevantes. "Agenda telefónica" no es el problema, sino un _while_ o lo que sea. Así más gente se puede beneficiar de lo debatido aquí

Comment: Excelente, lo tendre en cuenta para el futuro, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Date cuenta que cuando a `nuevocont` le das el valor de `n`, en ningun momento le das el valor de regreso de `s`. Entonces la condicion del while nunca se cumple. Tienes que asignarle el valor se `s` antes de la siguiente vuelta.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
struct agenda_telefonica{
    char nombre[30]={"Vacio"};
    char apellido[30];
    int prefijo;
    int telefono;
}contacto[10];

int main(){
    int seleccion,modificador;
    int i;
    char bandera='F';//determina si hay contactos o no
    char retorno='s',nuevocont='s';//para retornar a opciones e ingresar un nuevo contacto

    cout<<"***Agenda Telefonica***\n"<<endl;

    while(retorno=='s'){
        //Menu de opciones de la agenda
        cout<<"\aIngrese una opcion:\n";
        cout<<"1)Imprimir contactos\n";
        cout<<"2)Ingresar un contacto.\n";
        cout<<"3)Modificar un contacto.\n";
        cout<<"4)Eliminar un contacto.\n";
        cin>>seleccion;
        switch(seleccion){//para seleccionar el menu
            case 1://mostrar contactos
                if(bandera=='V'){//se imprimen contactos agendados
                    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
                        if(contacto[i].prefijo!=0){//muestra los contactos si prefijo es distinto a 0
                            cout<<"Contacto "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
                            cout<<contacto[i].nombre<<" "<<contacto[i].apellido<<"\n";
                            cout<<contacto[i].prefijo<<"-"<<contacto[i].telefono<<endl;
                        }
                    } 
                }else{//Si no hay contactos agendados
                    cout<<"***No hay contactos agendados***"<<endl;
                }
                break;
            case 2://ingresar contactos  
                nuevocont = 's';
                while(nuevocont=='s'){
                    cout<<"Ingrese la posicion donde quiere agregar el contacto: ";
                    cin>>modificador;
                    cin.ignore(256,'\n');//vaciar el buffer en linux 
                    cout<<"Ingrese su nombre: ";
                    cin.getline(contacto[modificador-1].nombre,30,'\n');
                    cout<<"ingrese su apellido: ";
                    cin.getline(contacto[modificador-1].apellido,30,'\n');
                    cout<<"Ingrese el prefijo: ";
                    cin>>contacto[modificador-1].prefijo;
                    cout<<"Ingrese su telefono: ";
                    cin>>contacto[modificador-1].telefono;

                    cout<<"\nDesea ingresar un nuevo contacto? (s/n): ";
                    cin>>nuevocont;//para determinar si queremos ingresar otro contacto  
                }
                bandera='V';//Bandera cambia luego de agendar contactos   
                break;
        }
        cout<<"\nDesea seleccionar otra opcion? (s/n): "<<endl;
        cin>>retorno; 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Te doy un consejo, dile que lo quieres poner en la posicion 11. Hay que añadir checkeos de seguridad amigo.

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!! Tenes razon!!!!